# Materilize side-nav always open, won't load collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

My side-nav should be loading collapsed and also showing a modal as in this fiddle:

Relevant code:
HTML:

```html
    <header class="text-center">
</header>
<div class="main_container">

<nav class="indigo darken-4">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo center"><h1>code.partners near you</h1></a>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
      <li class="bold"><a href="/auth/github" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Login with Github</a></li>
      <li class="bold"><a href="/marker" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Create a New Marker</a></li>
      <li class="bold"><a href="/logout" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Logout</a></li>
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<main>
{{!-- <div class="container text-center"> --}}
  <div id="map_container">
   <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="message_box">
      <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <div id="messageInputBox">
          <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{!-- </div> --}}

</main>
```

and my Javascript:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("interactive is linked and ready");

 // Initialize collapse button


  $(".button-collapse").sideNav({
      menuWidth: 240, // Default is 240
      edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
      closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    });
  // Initialize collapsible (uncomment the line below if you use the dropdown variation)
  //$('.collapsible').collapsible();


});//end document.ready
```

my Heroku page: 
http://coding-partners.herokuapp.com/home

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/clwarnock/h7md1q3u/8/

I'm trying to get my side-nav to act more as in the fiddle:

1. Start collapsed
2. Display a modal when open

Editing for Danny Buonocore

When the viewport is adjusted to a small device size, there's no hamburger menu to open it back up again. I think there's a conflict somewhere that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar is designed to automatically be expanded when the window is large enough.  This is known as [responsive web design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/?hl=en).  If you make your browser smaller, you will see that it won't be expanded on load.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks so much for responding! When i do adjust the screen smaller, the 'hamburger' menu still does not show, so I have no ability to open the menu.

Comment: I can't answer that part without seeing the code.  I'm assuming it's different from the one on the fiddle